# Airflow dags are not recognised when running the webserver as a daemon

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, airflow

I'm trying to setup airflow on a ubuntu server. I have written some dags that seem to work fine when I test them with `airflow test <dag_id> <task_id>`. I've run airflow as a daemon with the following command

```
airflow webserver -p 8080 -D
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080` I can't click on the dags in the airflow UI though. Instead I see a small icon next to the dag name:

[image]

The strange thing is that when I run airflow manually with the command

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

I can click on the dag!

[image]

I think this problem arises from the fact that the webserver has a different configuration when being run as a daemon compared to when being run manually. I don't understand why, since the webserver should look in the same spot for the dags in both cases right?

**Question:** How do I solve this issue? What is the reason that my dags are recognised when I'm running the webserver manually and not recognised when I'm running the webserver as a daemon process?

Comment: Are you setting your AIRFLOW_HOME via airflow.cfg or an env var?

Comment: @cwurtz Via airflow.cfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works (it probably has something to do with the location from which the daemon process runs) but it works:

Inside the different dag files I specified paths by pointing to the directory the dags where located (the `dags` folder). So it would define the log location like this:

```
log = ./log/etl_log.log
```

When running the webserver manually this caused no problems, but it did when running the webserver as a daemon process. Because after I changed the log location to

```
log = /home/user/airflow/dags/log/etl_log.log
```

I was able to access the dag in the ui.